# Bash if based on grep result gives "too many arguments" error?

Tags: bash, files, grep, battery

So I am trying to tell if the machine has a battery, then run different commands based on whether or not it does. Here's what I have so far:

```
upower -d >> /tmp/batstat
if [ grep -F BAT0 /tmp/batstat ]; then
    echo "BAT0 PRESENT" >> /tmp/batstat
else
    echo "NO BAT0" >> /tmp/batstat
fi
```

However, this returns the error "bash: [: too many arguments" while writing NO BAT0 to /tmp/batstat as expected. Running only the grep works properly, so I don't understand why it doesn't work as an if condition.

If there is a better way to check for a battery, I am 100% open to it.

Comment: `[` is interpreting `grep -F BAT0 /tmp/batstat` as four separate arguments, not the one or two it's expecting. I'm sure there are more idiomatic ways to do it, but I'd do it like so: `[ "$(grep -F 'text' test.txt)" != "" ]`. Not an answer, because unsure about battery: what OS are you running?

Comment: I'm using Debian Jessie.

Comment: Also, when I try using your recommendation with BAT0 in place of text (with or without single quotes), I get the following error: bash: $'NO BAT0\nNO BAT0\nNO BAT0\nNO BAT0\nNO BAT0\nNO BAT0': command not found

Answer (score 3):

```
if upower -d | grep -qF BAT0 ; then
   echo "BAT0 PRESENT"
else
   echo "NO BAT0"
fi
```

`if` will take a series of commands and works on the status of the final one, in this case the grep. `grep` returns true if it matches, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -F BAT0 /tmp/batstat` is in no way a CONDITIONAL EXPRESSION (as detailed in the fine manual) for the `test` builtin of `bash`. Since the output of `grep` is unused, the `-q` option and relying on the exit code likely suffices.

```
grep -F -q BAT0 batstat
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo yea
else
    echo nay
fi
```

Also, `/tmp/batstat` is likely a very poor choice, especially where a nefarious local user has access. Consider instead using [`mktemp(1)`](http://man.openbsd.org/man1/mktemp.1), or not locating the file under `/tmp`.

Comment: I didn't include this in the post but the script immediately does rm /tmp/batstat as soon as it is finished with the commands in the if statement. I only need to check if upower -d mentions BAT0 for this one if statement. This is for a Debian preseed installer so I'm not sure where else to write to.

Comment: I am thinking of using something like this:

    d-i upower -d >> /tmp/batstat
    d-i grep -F -q BAT0 /tmp/batstat
    d-i if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo yea
    else
        echo nay
    fi
    d-i rm /tmp/batstat